# linux redirect 100GB stdout to file fails

Tags: linux, shell, redirect, bigdata

I have this command that writes over 100GB of data to a file.

```
zfs send snap1 > file
```

Something appears to go wrong several hours into the process.  E.g., if I run the job twice, the output is slightly different.   If I try to process the file with

```
zfs receive snap2 < file
```

an error is reported after several hours.

For debugging purposes, I'm guessing that there's some low probability failure in the shell redirection.  Has anyone else seen problems with redirecting massive amounts of data?  Any suggestions about where to proceed?

Debugging this is tedious because small examples work, and running the large case takes over 3 hours each time.

Earlier I had tried pipes:

```
zfs send snap1| zfs receive snap2
```

However this always failed with much smaller examples, for which

```
zfs send snap1 > file; zfs receive snap2 < file
```

worked.   (I posted a question about that, but got no useful responses.) This is another reason that I suspect the shell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that the failure is in the shell (or OS) is negligible compared to a bug in zfs or a problem in how you are using it.

It just takes some minutes to test your hypothesis: compile this stupid program:

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

#define BUF 1<<20
#define INPUT 56

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char buf[BUF], rbuf[BUF], *a, *b;
  int len, i;
  memset(buf, INPUT, sizeof(buf));
  if (argc == 1)
  {
    while ((len = read(0, rbuf, sizeof(rbuf))) > 0)
    {
      a = buf; b = rbuf;
      for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
      {
        if (*a != *b)
          return 1;
        ++a; ++b;
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    while (write(1, buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

then try `mkfifo a; ./a.out w > a` in a shell and `pv < a | ./a.out` in another one, see how long does it take to get any bit flip.

It should get in the TiB region relatively fast...